# How to check whether a date is in j-n-Y format or not? if yes then how to convert it to d-m-Y format?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to find whether a date is in "j/n/Y" format or not, if its is then i want to convert ot to "d/m/Y". If it is already in "d/m/Y" format i dont want any alteration in it.

I tried this-

```
         $date = '1/7/2019';
```

here i am assuming 1 as date, 7 as month, and 2019 as year(obviously). Now,

```
        $date_format_changed = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
```

this above code gives me output as "07/01/2019". But i want output as "01/07/2019".

and if date is already in d/m/Y format eg- 17/12/2019, when this string will be passed in above date conversion code, it gives me output "01/01/1970". Dont know why.

Please help!

Comment: That's going to be very difficult to check. 1/7/2019 would be valid as both July 1st and January 7th. It's easier with days greater than 12, but less than that would be iffy.

Comment: The note for [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) says `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.`

Comment: If you know that the string always is either `j/n/Y` or `d/m/Y`, then you can check the length. If the length of the date string is 8 or 9, then it's the `j/n/Y`. If the length is 10, then it's `d/m/Y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach could be to `explode` the date into its day month and year components, and then analyse it

```
$date = '1/7/2019'; 

$array = explode("/", $date);

$day = $array[0];
$month = $array[1];
$year = $array[2];

if(strlen($day) == 1) $day = "0".$day;
if(strlen($month) == 1) $month = "0".$month;

echo $day."/".$month."/".$year;
```

Comment: You could simply do a `strlen($date)`. If the length is 8 or 9, it's `j/n/Y` and if it's 10, it's `d/m/Y`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson- Yes we can do that, but we still need to explode the $date variable to concatenate 0 with day and month, so that we can achieve date in d-m-Y format.

Answer (score 1):

You can "help" the interpreter to guess the correct format.

[date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is one way to do this.

```php
$date = '1/7/2019';
$parsed = date_create_from_format("j/n/Y", $date);

if ($parsed == false) {
    // Not in j/n/Y format
} else {
    $dmY = $parsed->format("d/m/Y");
}
```

Note that this will also parse dates which theoretically match j/n/Y but are intended in a different way. (e.g. when you use d/m/Y it might also detect m/d/Y)